# How can i limit a user's choice of using certain items from comboBox so once its exceeds that it either gives an error or disables the option in java?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have created a comboBox containing 6 items in java, I want to disable/remove/provide error message upon selection again for certain items if it exceeds the limits and also I have 2 items that the user cannot choose the same one after another so lets say, I have A,B,C,D,E,F. The user will not be able to choose option f more then twice so either after their selection second selection it gets disabled/remove/any further selection will provide an error. and for options D and F. If the user chooses option D as a first attempt they should not be able to choose that for second, and forth option, and sixth likewise if they choose D second time, they should not be able to choose that for first, third and fifth option, same for option F.

I have created 6 String variables optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, optionE, Optionf

below is my code for the comBobox

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>(new String[] { "A", "B",  "C", "D", "E", "F");
        comboBox.setBounds(20, 145, 185, 20);
        contentPane.add(comboBox);
```

Help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

As per your comment, in my limited experience, I have never seen anyone use `JCombobox`es to allow a user to select multiple elements, which is why I thought that you had 6 combo boxes and was showing just one. In this case, I think that the way to go is to use a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html):

```
    final JList<String> list = new JList<String>(new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"});
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            List<String> selectedItems = list.getSelectedValuesList();
            //Do your logic here.
        }
    });
```

Also, to answer your second question, the `&&` operator in java represents the binary `AND` operator.

Comment: Wouldn't what you are doing create more than 1 combobox private JComboBox jc1 = new JComboBox()... and you create 4 more. I have 1 comboBox with with 6 items.

Comment: btw, what is the && for, in if(jc1.getSelectedIndex() == 1 && ....) what do i put after

Comment: Hi, I am finding it difficult understand how to second set of code work, how am i able to implement with my situation?

Comment: @user3261660: I have changed my answer. This should hopefully answer your question.

Comment: So instead of a comboBox I  hould create JList? could you please give me an example of logic that can be go on the //Do you logic here. for example, what I do so that 2 D commands are not allowed directly after each other. Thanks.

Comment: @user3261660: I'm terribly sorry I do not know what I was thinking. I think that your problem can be tackled in an easier way: Have a `JComboBox` as per your original plan, and have a button. When you press a button, you can fire your logic and display everything in a JList so that the user can see his/her selection. The logic goes inside the event handler of the button. That should do what you are after.